# displaying CERTAIN information in a sql (below a certain value)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im making this messaging system and im having trouble. Basically, its a thread type system, sort of like facebook style messaging. User 1 sends user 75 a message (message 1 and thread 1) is created, and user 75 replys with a message (message 2 is created in thread 1) and so on and so on. Now im able to display everything perfectly.

Lets say it gets to a point where it user75 submits his 5th reply on that thread (message 13),
and user 1 deletes the message to clean up his inbox (NOW message 5 has the value of "deleted")..... if user 75 replies, then EVERY MESSAGE in that thread will show up again to him. I want it to work in a way, that user 75's reply will seem like a new thread to user 1 (but its not, how can i achive this in sql) 
here is the sql to display the messages in the thread

```
mysql>     SELECT message_id,thread_id,messages.user_id,to_id,messages.subject,messages.body,from_message_status,to_message_status,message_status,new,messages.date FROM messages 
    ->         INNER JOIN users ON users.id = messages.user_id
    ->         INNER JOIN messages_thread ON messages_thread.id = messages.thread_id
    ->         WHERE thread_id = 1
    ->         GROUP BY messages.message_id ORDER BY message_id ASC  ;
+------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----+------------+
| message_id | thread_id | user_id | to_id | subject | body                                                          | from_message_status | to_message_status | message_status | new | date       |
+------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----+------------+
|          1 |         1 |      75 |     1 |         | Wassup man.                                                   | unread              | unread            | deleted        |   0 | 1312493817 |
|          2 |         1 |       1 |    75 |         | im chilling , and you?                                        | unread              | unread            | read           |   0 | 1312493867 |
|          3 |         1 |      75 |     1 |         | Yea same same just posted man trying to find something to do. | unread              | unread            | deleted        |   0 | 1312493895 |
|          4 |         1 |      75 |     1 |         | what you trying to get into today?                            | unread              | unread            | deleted        |   0 | 1312493904 |
|          5 |         1 |      75 |     1 |         | just play some video games or something. you?                 | unread              | unread            | deleted        |   0 | 1312494046 |
|          6 |         1 |      75 |     1 |         | hello? dude?                                                  | unread              | unread            | read           |   0 | 1312494108 |
+------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----+------------+
```

Like do you see the last delete in message_status? im trying to display everything below that

Comment: If someone sends a message to more than one user are you going to put multiple rows?  If so you will have de-normalized data.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT ... FROM messages 
             INNER JOIN users ON users.id = messages.user_id
             INNER JOIN messages_thread ON messages_thread.id = messages.thread_id
             WHERE thread_id = 1 
             AND message_id > 
                (SELECT max(message_id) FROM messages 
                   WHERE thread_id = 1 and message_status = 'DELETED')
             GROUP BY messages.message_id ORDER BY message_id ASC  ;
```